# PyMongo: What happens to cursor when no_cursor_timeout=True

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Looking at the `cursor` docs for MongoDB, I don't see a way to delete a cursor. What happens in PyMongo if I am using a cursor with the `no_cursor_timeout` property set to True? Is the cursor deleted when my script terminates even if I have not gotten to the end of the cursor's results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python uses reference counting for object lifetime management, when the Cursor object goes out of scope the garbage collector would call __die() which closes the cursor.
If you want explicit control, you can call close() by yourself.

Comment: This is my instinct, but I don't see a close() member function for a PyMongo cursor object. Am I missing it?

Comment: See here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/cursor.py#L276

Comment: Thanks a lot! I never took a look at the source code, so this is quite interesting.

Comment: "reference counting...out of scope" what does this mean? Is this after a long time (so the cursor is waiting and not used for a long time which is bad) or rather quickly?