# mongoose: How to temporarily store a cursor?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How can I store these [cursors](http://thecodebarbarian.com/cursors-in-mongoose-45) temporarily on my Express server without clogging the memory?

I want to store them for less than 10 minutes, but don't know how to do it properly since it's not possible to store them in mongoDB itself.

Comment: Why you want to do that (It's very illogical wish)?

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853178/when-a-mongodb-cursor-will-expire). I think it can be interesting to look at :)

Comment: @Neodan For something like this (with 100 simultaneous clients):

1.I get data from client
2.I use data from client to run a mongoDB query
3.I get the results from mongoDB (cursor)
4.I ask a question to client
5.I get a reply from client
6.Depending on the reply from client, I filter the cursor (the results from the first mongoDB query)

Answer (score 2):

You can set timeout: true in find options
timeout (default:false) specify if the cursor can timeout.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, if cursor timeouts, how do I know this and make sure to free-up NodeJS's memory?

Comment: You can use cursor.close()

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#cursor-QueryCursor-js
Marks this cursor as closed. Will stop streaming and subsequent calls to